# Rails and Javascript in production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Hello Stack Overflow community! I am new to Ruby on Rails, and nearing the end of my first project, I am having a little bit of trouble with getting my app production ready.

My first problem was that I needed to refresh the page to get my personal jQuery to work. I fixed this problem by adding the jquery-turbolinks gem to the project and adding jquery.turbolinks to the manifest file.

However, this quick solution did not work for my production environment, for some reason. So I just changed the ordering of some stuff in my manifest file, changed config.serve_static_files to false and config.assets.compile to true (in production.rb). So now none of my JS works in production.

Then, from info gathered from the web, I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Now none of my JS or CSS effects are evident in production!

So finally, to undo that blunder, I ran bundle exec rake assets:clean. Now terminal is complaining that I have "untracked files" when committing changes with git.

Clearly, I'm in an absolutely messy situation. Other than this blunder, my project is running smoothly, so any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

PS: Everything works perfectly in development environment...

Comment: So, was there some sort of question in all of that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Though your issue was thoroughly explained, the best questions are ones which allow us to pinpoint a problem quickly, or at least provide us with a place to begin exploring a solution. These questions usually include code samples, error logs, the hosting platform being used, etc. You did a good job walking the reader through your issue, but for future reference, make it a goal to include some more concrete stuff  - it can help us arrive at solutions quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

From what you've explained, it seems that running precompile locally didn't quite work, and an attempt to run `rake assets:clean` has left Git saying there are changes that need to be committed.

In Sprockets, running `rake assets:clean` only removes old assets (keeps the most recent 3 copies) from public/assets - [[source](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md#rake-task)]. Running this command altered your public/assets directory, and these changes have not been committed, hence the terminal complaining.

If you wish to wipe `public/assets` and generate the assets from scratch, you can do the following:

```
rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Using `clobber` will destroy the assets directory, while the `precompile` command following it will rebuild the assets in a way that should reflect your production environment. Once you commit these changes and deploy, your new assets should display properly in production.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First, thank you very much for your help and time.

Does running clobber do anything inherently destructive to my project? Or will running clobber simply cause my asset pipeline to be reassembled in a sense?

Comment: Everything worked. Thanks so much. Will ask a more concrete question next time.